# Data file processing - Python

Tags: python, loops, iteration, text-processing

I have been assigned a task, and I cannot seem to figure out how I should proceed with it. It seemed relatively easy, but I must be doing something wrong, I would love it if someone could give me guidance. The code I have so far is:

```
infile = open("dataset.txt", "r")
outfile = open("emails.txt", "w")

def main():
  lines = infile.splitlines()
  for line in lines:
    if line.find("@", ".")!= -1:
      print(line)

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

In dataset.txt is the 20 Newsgroups data set(which is the data set that I am working with). The task is this: Find all valid sender e-mails (the email Ids that have the symbol “@” and “.”) in
the given data set and write them to a new file: “emails.txt”
Make sure you also display the number of characters in each email beside the
email address.Your file must not contain duplicate emails. At the end of your file, display the total numbers of emails in the file and their
average length.

Comment: you defined a function but never used it

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: @S.B, don't think so

Answer (score 1):

1. You defined a function but you didn't call it.
2. `str.find` method doesn't accept two strings. Its signature is `str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`. take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

As you've already done, you should iterate through the lines in the `dataset.txt` file. Then grab email addresses. Based on your data you can do it several ways.

It's totally fine to use `str` methods like what you did, I just decided to use a simple naive regex. This regex only checks if an string has `@` and `.` inside in the mentioned order. There are definitely more concise patterns if you search.

Finally add the email addresses to a set so that duplicates are removed:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\b(?=\S*@\S*\.\S*)\S*\b")

emails = {
    item
    for line in open("dataset.txt").readlines()
    for item in pattern.findall(line)
}

with open("emails.txt", "w") as f:
    for email in emails:
        print(len(email), email, file=f)
```

For `.find()` method, you should check `"@"` and `"."` in separate calls, not together. First check the return value of `.find("@")` and then check too see if there is any dot after this by `.find(".", N)`. `N` is the returned value of the previous find:

```py
emails = set()
with open("dataset.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        lst = line.split()
        for item in lst:
            idx_1 = item.find("@")
            if idx_1 == -1:
                continue
            idx_2 = item.find(".", idx_1)
            if idx_2 != -1:
                emails.add(item)


with open("emails.txt", "w") as f:
    for email in emails:
        print(len(email), email, file=f)
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the whole code will look like, so what you are saying is to change the .find() method - as in check both separately?

Comment: @user9223978 I've updated the answer with the `str.find()` solution.

Comment: Thanks! but i also do not think that I am allowed to use sets, dictionaries is what I am allowed to use.

Comment: @user9223978 Sets are kind of dictionaries that only have keys. The idea is the same. Change it however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Python's re (Regular Expressions) library to identify valid email addresses in the dataset file.

```
import re

EMAIL_PATTERN = r'([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5})'

def main():
  with open('dataset.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    lines = in_file.read().splitlines()
    with open('emails.txt', 'a') as out_file:
        for line in lines:
            match = re.search(EMAIL_PATTERN, line)
            if match is not None:
                out_file.write(match.group(1) + '\n')

main()
```